# Why is there a 6th team member in 5v5 tournaments sitting on the side?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, competitive-gaming

I was looking at the ELeague photos, and often in them you can see a 6th player in uniform on the side.

http://www.e-league.com/lcq-gallery/rjusz8h8jniodazpeldexffvukfyol

[image: e-Sport team with 6 people]

Who is this and what can he do? Its not a 6th player (games are played 5v5), but it seems that he can communicate with the team (you can see he has a mic).
It's not a referee too, because he's in the team uniform.

So who is this guy, and what does he do?

Edit: Also, what does that team member have access to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[He's the team Coach](http://read.navi-gaming.com/en/team_news/csgo_coach) At some tournaments the coach has a chair and sits behind the team, sometimes there isn't even a chair, here he seam to be covered well by the organizers.